# Only match word outside a HTML statement with a regex

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

The thing I want to achieve with the code below: match a specified word case-insensitive and only once in a text and replace it with a link.

I have the following preg_match to match the word 'foo' in a string:

```
if (preg_match("/\bfoo\b/i", $text, $results, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE)) { 
  // substr_replace the word 'foo' for a link <a href.. 
}
```

No problem for a text without HTML, but imagine the following text with HTML:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <a href="/foo-bar/" title="foo bar">some other foo link</a> consectetur adipiscing elit foo bar.
```

In this case there will be a new link within the current link, because there will be a match with foo in the href-part (same problem for the title and name part).

How can the pattern be changed to match only the 'foo' outside a HTML statement?

Answer (score 3):

[Don't parse HTML with regular expressions](http://welbog.homeip.net/glue/53/XML-is-not-regular). Use [XPath](http://www.w3schools.com/XPath/default.asp) instead. PHP can easily [make use of it](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_simplexml_xpath.asp).

The XPath expression for what you want is pretty straightforward. Assuming the tag that you want to search inside is a `div`, this is what you want:

```
//div/text()[contains(.,'foo')]
```

Once you have the text node, you can run a regular expression on it without the fear of it containing any HTML tags.

Comment: Good point, but in this case there will be only some links with a fixed format and no other HTML in the text. So using XPath might be overfill.

Comment: Well, using regular expressions is *impossible*. I'll take overkill over impossible any day of the week.

Answer (score 0):

You could count the number of opening and closing brackets that have been encountered so far. If they differ, it means that you've opened a bracket without having yet encountered the closing one, which means you're presently inside a HTML tag.

However, note that in general, using regular expressions for HTML parsing is [a terrible idea](http://oubliette.alpha-geek.com/2003/12/31/do_not_do_not_parse_html_with_regexs).